# Autohotkey: how to determine if a text file is opened in emac or notepad3

Tags: autohotkey

I need to determine the path and file name of an open text file, whether it is opened in Notepad3 or in Emacs.

For both editors the path and file name are displayed in the window title of the opened file. Hence, I can use the AHK function `WinGetTitle` to extract the window title, and then the function `SubStr` to extract the path and file name from the window title.

However, the two editors differ in how the path and filename are displayed in the window title. In Notepad3 the title format is [filename][path], while in Emacs (my configuration) the format is [path][filename].

I would like my code to be usable regardless which of the two editors the text file is opened in. I guess I have to use some sort of an if-statement.

My pseudo code looks like this:

```
::uuu::   
    ; find the window title of the opened txt file
    WinGetTitle, windowTitle, A

    ; determine if text file is opened in Notepad3 or in Emacs
    appName = <some function> 

    ; construct file name and file path from window title
    if appName = notepad3
       fileName := SubStr(windowTitle,3,24)
       filePath := SubStr(windowTitle,29,-12)

    elseif appName = emacs
       fileName := SubStr(windowTitle,-23)
       filePath := SubStr(windowTitle,1,-24)

    end  

    ; send input to file           
     SendInput, %windowTitle%  {enter}
     SendInput, %fileName%     {enter}
     SendInput, %filePath%     {enter}         
return
```

1) what AHK function can be used to determine `appName`?

2) if `appName` can be determined, how should the `if-statement` in my code be made in correct AHK syntax?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out one way to solve my own question:

```
::uuu::   
    ; find the window title of the opened txt file
    WinGetTitle, windowTitle, A

    ; find the process or app used to open the text file
    WinGet, process, ProcessName, A

    ; construct file name and file path from window title
    if (process = "Notepad3.exe")
    {       
        fileName := SubStr(windowTitle,3,24)
        filePath := SubStr(windowTitle,29,-12)
    }

    else if (process = "emacs.exe")
    {
        fileName := SubStr(windowTitle,-23)
        filePath := SubStr(windowTitle,1,-24) 
    }  

    ; send input to file           
     SendInput, %windowTitle%  {enter}
     SendInput, %fileName%     {enter}
     SendInput, %filePath%     {enter}     

     SendInput, %process%     {enter}   

return
```